# How to skip before_update if before_create was called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

I'm trying to keep a user model "in sync" with a third party.

So in my User.rb:

```
before_create { ThirdParty.create!(user: self) }
before_update { ThirdParty.update!(user: self) }
```

The problem arises when I:

```
User.create!...
```

as both callbacks will be invoked (`before_create` then `before_update`).

This is how I got around this behaviour for now:

```
before_create {
 @before_create_called = true
 ThirdParty.create!(user: self)
}
before_update {
 return unless @before_create_called
 ThirdParty.update!(user: self)
}
```

But I'm not very confident/comfortable with this solution. Is there a better way to approach this?

**EDIT**

*I'm sorry*, of course this was my mistake, thanks to @Max Williams I wanted to get to the bottom of this, so for the curious:

I also had a:

```
after_create { A.new() }
```

Which somewhere in its bowels did this:

```
user.toggle(:active)
```

now it does this:

```
user.update_attributes(active: true).
```

and didn't realize that `toggle` skips [validations and callbacks](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/toggle)

Comment: They should never be called as part of the same save.  If it is a new record (no id) it will call `before_create` and if not it will call `before_update`.   Are you sure that it is calling both callbacks when you save?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I had byebug breakpoints in both callbacks, so yeah seems like it.

Comment: If this really is the case (and i'm still not convinced) then it means that your version of Rails is behaving differently to normal.  If that is the case then this could just be the tip of the iceberg.  I would try to find out **why** before_create and before_update are being called on the same save, rather than just try to work around it, or you could be hitting lots of other strange problems further down the line.

Comment: @MaxWilliams of course I had a bug in my code. Thanks for your comments!

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to keep the third party synced on each save, but just want to change the action based on whether the record is being created or updated try:

```
before_save do
  self.new_record? ? ThirdParty.create!(user: self) : ThirdParty.update!(user: self)
end
```